# Adding element before div only after checking using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am adding a label before a div on button click like this:

```
$(".deletebutton").before("<label></label>");
```

where `.deletebutton` is a `div`. But I see that with multiple clicks multiple labels are added. I want to check if a label exists before the div already. If it does I don't want to add another one.

My HTML structure is this:

```
<li>
    <label></label>
    <div class="deletebutton"></div>
<li>
```

Please suggest

[UPDATE] any better solution ?
This worked for me

```
if ($(".deletebutton").prev().get(0).tagName != 'LABEL') {
    $(".deletebutton").before("<label></label>");
} else {
    $(".deletebutton").prev().remove();
    $(".deletebutton").before("<label></label>");
}
```

what if we want to check for parents:

@silentw what if there is a div added each time around .deletebutton ?

i used following code but it is not working:

```
var parentTag = $(".ruRemove").parent().get(0).tagName;

if (parentTag == 'LI') {
    $(".ruRemove").wrap("<div class='data deletebutton'></div>");
    $(".deletebutton").before("<label></label>");
} else {

    var par = $('.deletebutton').parent();
    if (par.is('div')) par.remove();
    $(".ruRemove").wrap("<div class='data deletebutton'></div>");

    var prev = $('.deletebutton').prev();
    if (prev.is('label')) prev.remove();
    $('.deletebutton').before("<label></label>");
}

<label> </label>
<div class="deletebutton">
    <label> </label>
    <div class="deletebutton">
        <label> </label>
        <div class="deletebutton">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(".deletebutton").on('click', function() {
    if(!$(this).prev().is('label')) $(this).before("<label>A</label>");
});
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ph1802p9/1/)</kbd>

### Update

```
$(".deletebutton").on('click', function() {
    var prev = $(this).prev();
    if(prev.is('label')) prev.remove();
    $(this).before("<label>This is a label</label>");
});
```

<kbd>[**DEMO 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/ph1802p9/3/)</kbd>

Comment: Do you know you can build demos right into stackoverflow...Learn to use the snipplet button.

Comment: @DotnetSparrow Your updated code would fail if there is no prev() element. Enjoy that

Comment: @silentw With your edit, your logic is wrong in the if. It will always be true and is doing the opposite. The not() should be an is()

Comment: @epascarello Thanks for the heads up, I interpreted the question wrong. Now it's fixed!

Comment: @silentw what if there is a div added each time around

Comment: @silentw I have added a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27067777/adding-div-around-link-using-jquery