# adding div around link using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am adding a div around a link on click of a button. but when i click button multiple times, it adds multiple divs.

```
    <li>
    <label> </label>
    <div class="deletebutton">
        <label> </label>
        <div class="deletebutton">
            <label> </label>
            <div class="deletebutton">
<input type="button" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctrlAddPhotos_RadUpload1remove1" value="Remove" class="ruButton ruRemove" name="RemoveRow">
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
```

How can i make sure that it first checks if there is a div around link and then adds.

I am using following code:

```
var parentTag = $(".ruRemove").parent().get(0).tagName;

if (parentTag == 'LI') {
    $(".ruRemove").wrap("<div class='data deletebutton'></div>");
    $(".deletebutton").before("<label></label>");
} else {

    var par = $('.deletebutton').parent();
    if (par.is('div')) par.remove();
    $(".ruRemove").wrap("<div class='data deletebutton'></div>");

    var prev = $('.deletebutton').prev();
    if (prev.is('label')) prev.remove();
    $('.deletebutton').before("<label></label>");
}
```

it should become this:

```
  <li>
                <label> </label>
                <div class="deletebutton">
    <input type="button" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctrlAddPhotos_RadUpload1remove1" value="Remove" class="ruButton ruRemove" name="RemoveRow">
                </div>
        </li>
```

when i click button. before clicking html is:

```
  <li>             
    <input type="button" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctrlAddPhotos_RadUpload1remove1" value="Remove" class="ruButton ruRemove" name="RemoveRow">  
        </li>
```

Comment: Its not very clear to me what you are looking for.  Can you show before and after HTML fragments to describe the effect desired?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution shown in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qgswz3bq/).

The code story is

**HTML**

```
<button id="myButton">My Button</button
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
    $("#myButton").click(function() {
        if ($(this).parent().get(0).tagName !== "DIV") {
            $(this).wrap("<div class='myDiv'>");
        }
    });
});
```

What the code does is register a callback for a button click.  When clicked, we ask for the parent of the button that was clicked and ask if the parent node has a tag name of "DIV" meaning it is a `<div>`.  If it is **not** a div, then we wrap the button in a div and end.  On the next call, the detection of the parent being a div will be true and no new div will be added.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use for example a function that does what you want only on the first click?

So only on the first click of that button adds the div, if you click other times the button, it wont do anything. This way you wont add multiple divs.

To do that you could use for example jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#firstclick").one("click",function() {
        alert("This will be displayed only once.");
    });

</script>
```

You can check even the jQuery API Documentation regarding one:

http://api.jquery.com/one/